# Как правильно устанавливать Docker?

Tags: docker

На оф сайте не нашёл нормального вменяемого объяснения , не ужели он устанавливается через Командную строку ?

Comment: А что именно вас смущает?

Comment: какой не будь установщик , а как это делать ?

Comment: в случае с windows есть и установщик и мануал https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/ в случае с linux все различается только набором команд и необходимостью подключения репозитория для установки.

Comment: я смотрел эту сылку - не увидел там установщика ,.

Comment: Уточните, на какую операционную систему вы хотите поставить докер?

Comment: Docker Toolbox упоминающийся в разделе Installation и есть установщик docker и соответствующего окружения под windows

Comment: в низу дали ответ , я просто не знал что это так называется , спасибо вам

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Цитирую [документацию Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/):

> Installation
>
> If you have VirtualBox running, you must shut it down before running the installer.
>
> 1. Go to the [Docker Toolbox](https://www.docker.com/toolbox) page.
> 2. Click the installer link to download.
> 3. Install Docker Toolbox by double-clicking the installer.

Перед этим вам необходимо убедиться, что виртуализация поддерживается вашим CPU и разрешена в настройках BIOS и вашей ОС.

Comment: с виртуалбоксом я работаю стабильно и постоянно , за ссылку спасибо но не знал что докер и докер толбокс это одно и тоже и вес меня этого докера вообще понравился

Comment: @LenovoID это не одно и то же. Тем не менее, выбора у вас нет, т.к. необходимое вам приложение работает только на Linux (есть еще Docker, работающий с Hyper-V, но вам нужен не он).

Comment: @Etki как вы догадались, какое именно приложение нужно автору? Мне вот не очевидно.

Comment: Мне нужен Докер для виртуализации проектов но не ВиртуалБокс

Comment: Но правда для начала надо его освоить чем и буду заниматься

Comment: @NickVolynkin я самонадеянный волшебник (надевает шляпу, испаряется).

Comment: @LenovoID вы не сможете его запустить иначе как в линуксе, а для этого вам нужен линукс, а на винде вы сможете только поднять виртуалку для этого.

Comment: Etki у меня установлен Линукс , я постоянно в нём , вы напишите ответ только если можно подробно , и я ваш ответ выберу лучшим , просто надо это сделать мне я думал что под винду есть докер а как Вы говорите что нет

Comment: @LenovoID ну, разработчики Docker упорно утверждают, что есть. Но фактически это обёртка легковесного дистра с Докером в виртуальную машину. Слишком туго он прибит гвоздями к особенностям ядра Linux.

Comment: @LenovoID так вы в линуксе докер ставите или в винде?

Comment: в Лине естественно , раз под другие ОС ни чего нет

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас в публичную бету вышел [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/), он поднимает виртуалку в `Hyper-V`. Правда он ограничен версией винды, только `Windows 10` начиная с определенного билда